# Javascript / Why mycode is not synchronous

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have discover that a custom code is not syncronous as I thought.

I have this pseudo code:

```
 ObjectA = function () 
 {
  var pointer;
  var value =[];
  this.set_pointer  = function (p) {pointer = p;}
  this.return_value = function () {return value[pointer];}
 }

 ObjectB = function () 
 {
  var SCOPE = this;
  var OBJ = new ObjectA();
 ....
  this.reset = function () 
  {   OBJ.set_pointer(0);}



 this.draw = function (what) 
 { 
   SCOPE.update();
   OBJ.set_pointer(from);

   OBJ.get_value();

  // do somethings with Three.js
  // draw some lines and some little pointclouds.

  // do some things
  // update two text elements           
  }



}

Main = new ObjectB();    
Main.draw(7);
Main.reset();
```

ObjectA is using arraybuffers, dataviews and typedarrays.
ObjectB is using Three.js to draw some very symple  3D things.

The problem is inside 'draw'.
OBJ.get_value(); is using the pointer value 0 (zero) instead 7. 
Abnormally (as I think)  main.draw(7) is not executed first and later Main.reset(); It seems that Main.reset() is inmediatelly executed, so I have 0 (zero)

I'm not going to wait any DOM synchronism.

What can be the reason of this bechaviour?. Maybe the Three,js use ? The OOP style I'm using ?

Is there any way to check why is this happen?

Any idea would be appreciated

NOTE: Sorry for use the Three.js tag.

Comment: You left out too much code for it to be clear what's going wrong.

Comment: @Pointy ... Mmm, believe me, the code is not large neither complex. If you think that that can be the reason, please give some advices

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle.net sample where we can run the code repeating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I have found the  reason (or I think ) of a NO synchonism

Sometimes  'this' could be pointing to 'window' instead of the self instance of your object.

Sometimes, a bad use of this (when it is 'window') can raise an error you have not taken into account. Then a next line of code can be executed, and sometimes you can have the impression of an incorrect (not syncronous) operation.

So.... review the bad use of 'this'....